# Using BitmapImage in Silverlight, losing my DPI info

Tags: silverlight, dpi, bitmapimage

I'm trying to load a high-resolution (300 dpi) image into a BitmapImage object (which will be displayed in an Image control nested within a Canvas).

The problem is that when I save the image to the hard drive, it's losing it's dpi information. I'm using a PNG encoder which has no compression, so I know that's not the problem.

Is it losing quality from the loading into the BitmapImage object?

If anyone is wondering why I'm doing this, it's because I'm implementing a small tool which will edit an image, and then save locally to have it printed, therefore I cannot lose quality.

Comment: Dare I suggest you provide some code so we can see how you are loading the BitmapImage? You may be inadvertently scaling it, but with only a text description we can only guess (hence the lack of replies).